# Ошибка в mysql | |Mysqldump

Tags: mysql

разбираюсь в книге Робин Никсон сооздаем динамимечские веб сайты.застраял на mysqldump.работаю через командую строку. я не понимаю почему не работает команда....
mysqldum -p root -p hom а именно переносит его на новую строку и добавить ";" то выдает ошибку error 1064 (42000) то что не правильный синтаксис...что тогда делать не понятно....

Comment: Потому что mysqldump это не sql-код, а отдельная такая программа

Comment: и как быть тогда?в книге то другого примера то нету.и вся работа идет через консоль

Comment: Откройте окно командного процессора (запустите CMD.EXE). Перейдите в каталог, в котором располагается утилита mysqldump (например, это может быть `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin`). Выполните свою команду.

Comment: я xampp использую

Answer (score 0):

Oшибку 1064 отдает утилита `mysql`, т.к. она ожидает запрос.

1. Выйдите из утилиты `mysql` (`quit` или `exit`)
2. Запустите `mysqldump -u user -p  database`

Comment: если сделать как вы написали то соровно идет переход на новую строку как будто там есть продолжения

Comment: @JinSilver подправил команду, пароль не указывается в команде. Может просит ввести пароль? Или выполняет дапм.

Comment: рабочий пример: root@mysql:~# mysqldump -u root -p Test
Enter password: 
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.7.24, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: Test
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1-log

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */; ...